# Is there any opensource Flash+PHP multyuser whiteboard?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, whiteboard

Is there any opensource Flash+PHP multyuser whiteboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own Whiteboard with Flash and Flash Streaming Server (Flash Communication Server MX) using shared objects.

[Creating a Whiteboard Application](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashcom/articles/whiteboard.html)

nowadays theres no opensource project, even you can use java to construct your own whiteboard!

update: you will create somethin like this.

[Whiteboard](http://www.flashcomguru.com/components/whiteboard/)

Answer (score 0):

Anything multi-user requires a live server protocol such as RTSP. If you have the budget, I recommend buying a "flash streaming server" from a company, then read up on how to use it on [Adobe's Site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/). Hope you figure it out.